# Is there any point in having proxy config instead a match-all Location?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf, proxypass

I have inherited a system and there are a few things that no one knows why there are how there are anymore.

In the httpd configuration, I've come across a few occurrences of Location directives that match all paths:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:4500/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4500/
</Location>
```

Isn't the above just equivalent to not having the Location directive?

```
    ProxyPass "/" http://localhost:4500/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse "/" http://localhost:4500/
```

Is there any advantage of the first over the second?

Comment: when using proxypass directives it is "clearer" to have them defined without location, generally placing them inside Location confuse the hell of a lot of people, but both examples you have shown are equally correct.

Comment: This is just a guess, but in the first case you could and some requirements like allow only from localhost or other ip.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two cases. You can define your config in either way. I can see only a difference in port numbers and `acquire` parameter (I don't think you are asking about them).

You can also remove the slashes `/` to read:

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: Sorry, that with the `port` and `acquire` was a typo, I've edited it. But I think I need the slashes when not using `Location`, otherwise `apachectl -t` complains "ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch needs a path when not defined in a location"

Comment: @nprensen: The path is optional as stated in apache documentation.

Comment: Yes, but it also says "When used inside a <Location> section, the first argument is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the <Location>.". And I do get that error when I omit it and I use no Location